# How to check if file is empty before loading using jquery load method?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If try to load an empty into a html ul list, the performance is really slow but when loading this same file but with data, using the same logic, no performance problems, I can click any buttons on the web page without any delay.

The best solution I can come up with is how to check if the file is empty before loading it.

```
          $("#logList").load("logFile", function(response, status, xhr)
          {
                  if(status == "error")
                  {
                      xhr.abort();
                  }

          });
```

Comment: You can't really see if the file is empty before it's loaded with ajax. Your code loads the file or encounters an error, and then the callback function is executed. To see if the file is empty before loading it, create a serverside script that does just that, and call it with ajax.

Comment: is there a way I can load it into a variable and check if the variable is empty before loading it into a live DOM?

Comment: Yes, instead of using `.load()` use `$.get`.  I would think loading an empty file would be faster than loading one with data... are you sure it's empty and not erroring or timing out?