# How to load the content of a file into variable using jquery load method?

Tags: ajax, jquery

How do I load the content of a file into a variable instead of the DOM using jQuery `.load()` method?

For example,

```
$("#logList").load("logFile", function(response){ });
```

Instead of loading the file into the `#logList` element of the DOM, I would like it to load into a variable.

Comment: Don't use `.load()` then, use another method http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/.

Comment: This should have been included with [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582920/how-to-check-if-file-is-empty-before-loading-using-jquery-load-method)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get` that atuomagically inserts the content into a DOM element, so do:

```
$.get("logFile", function(response) {
     var logfile = response;
});
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to initiate a GET request. In the success callback, you can set the result to your variable:

```
var stuff;
$.get('logFile', function (response) {
    stuff = response;
});
```

Please note that this is an **asynchronous operation**. The callback function will run when the operation is completed, so commands after `$.get(...)` will be executed beforehand.

That's why the following will log `undefined`:

```
var stuff;
$.get('logFile', function (var) {
    stuff = var;
});
console.log(stuff); //undefined
```

Comment: You can't actually use 'var' as a variable name.  function (var) => can be => function (data); stuff = data

Comment: Thank you _very_ much for noting this was asynchronous, that one comment unlocked the whole issue I was having and lead me to learn about .done etc [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).