# Inserting html code from one page, into another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, windows

I am a bit new to web based material so please bear with me.

I have two html pages on my local drive. Test1.html and test2.html.

How could I take test2.html's contents and place them into test1.html's body?

I have looked into using `w3IncludeHTML();` along with things like jQuery `.load()`

Test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="text"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#text').load("test2.html");
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Test2.html

```
<ul class='myclass'>
    <li>test li one</li>
    <li>test li two</li>
    <li>test li three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you include the jQuery library before your script your code should work if you change test2.txt to test2.html

Comment: along with what @mplungjan said, you need the correct name of the file in `.load()`

Comment: `$('#text').load("test2.txt");` and you state `Test2.html` which one is it? This is a typo question; the code works.

Comment: Now you went and edited it; your code works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is .html. Sorry. I forgot to change back the extension during testing.

Comment: @mplungjan wouldn't this only work within a server and not my local pc alone?

Comment: ........it works locally as `file:///` - look at your console.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have attempted that and it seems to still not work. I kept researching and found "You can't load a file from your local filesystem, like this, you need to put it on a a web server and load it from there. On the same site as you have the JavaScript loaded from." Have you testing File:/// and got it to work yourself in my scenario locally?

Comment: *"You can't load a file from your local filesystem, like this"* - that's kind of a crock. This is probably just a local issue that your browser has a setting's issue and/or a plugin preventing the file from loading/script from executing or your OS. The only way that I can see from where that comment comes from, would be if the script read as `script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/`. - what's that url that said that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131606/discussion-between-brandon-and-fred-ii).

Comment: BTW, in jQuery, you should wrap your code in `$(function() {` ... `});` otherwise it might execute before the browser's DOM is ready for it,

Comment: @JohnHascall the code is after the `<p>` that contains it so it is existing in th DOM at execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our chat:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131606/discussion-between-brandon-and-fred-ii

You need to run this as an admin, since this is a permissions issue under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the jquery/ajax approach:

Test1.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="text"></p>    
</body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'get_file_contents.php',
        data:'file=Test2',
        success:function(content){
            var content = $.trim(content);
            $('#text').append(content);
        }
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

This is a sample of "get_file_contents.php"

```
<?php
    $file=$_POST["file"].".html";
    $file_content=file_get_contents($file);

    echo $file_content;
?>
```

This example assumes that:

1. Your web server is running php
2. all 3 files (Test1.html, Test2.html and get_file_contents.php are in the same folder).

Hope that helped you

Comment: This is done locally on the desktop of a pc without a server set in place.

Comment: he doesn't want to setup a webserver/php

Comment: Without a "server" functionality, you are missing a lot of features... Why don't you setup a server in your pc? http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just saw your reply... Well if "server" is out of the equation, I can't think of something else :(

Comment: @captaintheo it was a permissions issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/41348242/1415724

Comment: @Brandon I have found this answer regarding getting the contents of a file and putting them into a variable... (In my answer, the variable is "content") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583271/how-to-load-the-content-of-a-file-into-variable-using-jquery-load-method

Answer (score -1):

Your browser is preventing this from working because "security".  If you open your browser's (JavaScript) Console, you'll no doubt find an error like this:

[image: Cross Origin Request not supported for file: schema]

As you allude to in your comments, the only solution is to run a webserver locally and use an http[s]:// schema.

Comment: *"As you allude to in your comments, the only solution is to run a webserver locally and use an http[s]:// schema."* - Not necessarily. This might just be a Windows permissions issue and need to probably run under admin and/or allow it. I will agree it is a permissions issue, but saying that the only solution is to run as a webserver isn't the only solution.

Comment: DId you not read the chat's transcript that Brandon and I had? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131606/discussion-between-brandon-and-fred-ii He said it himself. If you feel that my answer is wrong and that Brandon was also wrong, then you need to ping him and contest it.

Comment: I noticed you deleted your comment that I was responding to John. It disappeared soon as I posted my comment to you up there.